# Is it possible to integrate Moodle 1.9.x with woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, integration, moodle

So that is the question. I need it because I create my course in Moodle 1.9.x. I need to integrate it with woo-commerce. It would be great if any one helped me.

Comment: Moodle 1.9 is very old now, I would suggest for use moodle 2.x

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that would be better posted on the [Moodle jobs database](https://moodle.org/jobs/) or directly to a [Moodle partner](http://moodle.com/partners).